# Graphviz top to bottom AND left to right

Tags: uml, diagram, graphviz

Hi there I want to have a uml sequence diagram with dot language, now I have the following problem I want to have the layout as follows with a, b, c and d in a straight line at top but with the lines going straight to the bottom. How can I achieve that?

```
a   b   c   d
|   |   |   | 
|   |   |   |
```

perhaps can I achieve that the a, b, c and d with its belonging edges are clusters where I set a different rankdir for the clusters?

**EDIT** Just found a solution by adding invisible edges between a, b, c and d but any other solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you describe seems to be what `dot` does by default.

For example, this graph:

```
digraph SO {
  a -> a1 -> a2
  b -> b1 -> b2
  c -> c1 -> c2
  d -> d1 -> d2
}
```

Comes out like this:

[image]

If you have a more complex graph you can force nodes to be at the same height using `rank=same`.  For example:

```
digraph SO {
  { rank = same
    a b c d
  }

  a -> a1 -> a2 
  b -> b1 -> b2 -> b3 -> b4
  c -> c1 
  d -> d1 -> d2 -> d3
  d2 -> a2
}
```

Comes out like this:

[image]

However, if you want `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` to be in a specific order I think you're going to have to use invisible edges like you suggested.  The `dot` guide even recommends this:

> Edge weights also play a role when
>   nodes are constrained to the same
>   rank. Edges with non-zero weight
>   between these nodes are aimed across
>   the rank in the samedirection
>   (left-to-right, or top-to-bottom in a
>   rotated drawing) as far as possible.
>   This fact may be exploited to adjust
>   node ordering by placing invisible
>   edges (`style="invis"`) where needed.

Comment: ah sorry for sure when you now add d2 -> a2 I still want to be a, b, c and d on top but a1, a2, a3 still in one line as above

Comment: Whatever is hosting those images is now sending an ad instead. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 18):

Where there is a will there is a way!

This is an example on how to do that using dot:

```
digraph SEQ_DIAGRAM {
    graph [overlap=true, splines=line, nodesep=1.0, ordering=out];
    edge [arrowhead=none];
    node [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label=""];

    {
        rank=same;
        node[shape=rectangle, height=0.7, width=2];
        api_a[label="API A"];
        api_b[label="API B"];
        api_c[label="API C"];
    }
    // Draw vertical lines
    {
        edge [style=dashed, weight=6];
        api_a -> a1 -> a2 -> a3;
        a3 -> a4 [penwidth=5, style=solid];
        a4 -> a5;
    }
    {
        edge [style=dashed, weight=6];
        api_b -> b1 -> b2 -> b3 -> b4;
        b4 -> b5 [penwidth=5; style=solid];
    }
    {
        edge [style=dashed, weight=6];
        api_c -> c1;
        c1-> c2 [penwidth=5, style=solid];
        c2 -> c3 -> c4 -> c5;
    }
    // Draws activations
    { rank=same; a1 -> b1 [label="activate()"]; b1 -> c1 [arrowhead=normal]; }
    { rank=same; a2 -> b2 [style=invis]; b2 -> c2 [label="refund()", arrowhead=normal, dir=back]; }
    { rank=same; a3 -> b3 [arrowhead=normal, dir=back, label="place_order()"]; b3 -> c3; }
    { rank=same; a4 -> b4 [label="distribute()", arrowhead=normal]; }
    { rank=same; a5 -> b5 [style=invis]; b5 -> c5 [label="bill_order()", arrowhead=normal]; }
}
```

After rendered, this will yield this image:

[image: Sequence Diagram]

There are some important hints on how this was achieved:

- Each component have a list of nodes which have no shape, no height and no width.
- Each line must be at the same rank, otherwise DOT will position them accordingly to their automatic ranking.
- In order to make things straight, all directions are the same: from a to b to c. If you invert some of them, DOT will make a mess. The trick to achieve the right direction on the arrow is to use dir edge attribute.
- Weight attribute on edges is very important to keep vertical lines straight. They must outnumber the biggest rank. If you need to create a diagram where a rank will go as deep as 100, your weight must be 101 at least or it will be impossible to have a straight dashed vertical line.
- In order to get a straigh horizontal line, you have to connect each node on the same rank. Otherwise, DOT will bend the line. For instance, connecting a1 to c1 is achieved by connecting a1 to b1 and b1 to c1.

Answer (score 8):

You could try mscgen (message sequence chart generator)

A simple diagram would be example.msc

```
msc {

A,B;

--- [label="Start", ID="1"];

A->B [label="signal"];
A<-B [label="signal"];

}
```

$: mscgen -T png -o example.png -i example.msc.

Thats it is generates nice sequence diagram.

Thanks,
Srikanth Kyatham

Answer (score 3):

## Suggestion #1 - PlantUML

PlantUML uses Graphviz, so one option is to simply use PlantUML.  For example, in PlantUML this...

```
@startuml
Bob -> Alice : hello
@enduml
```

...is rendered as this...

[image: PlantUML rendered sequence diagram example]

The above diagram was rendered at [http://plantuml.com/plantuml/...](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000), and you can read up on PlantUML sequence diagrams [in the documentation](http://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram).  Also, PlantUML can also be used from [the command line](http://plantuml.com/starting), and PlantUML [plugins are available for many popular IDEs](http://plantuml.com/running).

## Suggestion #2 - NEATO

You can also use [Graphviz](https://graphviz.gitlab.io) & [NEATO](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/neatoguide.pdf) (PDF).  For example, this directed graph...

```
digraph sequenceDiagramExample {
  bobHead [ label="Bob" pos="0,1.5!" shape="record" ];
  bobPoint0 [ pos="0,0.75!" shape="point" width="0" ]
  bobFoot [ label="Bob" pos="0,0!" shape="record" ];
  aliceHead [ label="Alice" pos="1,1.5!" shape="record" ];
  alicePoint0 [ pos="1,0.75!" shape="point" width="0" ]
  aliceFoot [ label="Alice" pos="1,0!" shape="record" ];
  bobHead -> bobPoint0 -> bobFoot [ dir="none" style="dashed" ]
  aliceHead -> alicePoint0 -> aliceFoot [ dir="none" style="dashed" ]
  bobPoint0 -> alicePoint0 [ label="hello" labelloc="c" style="solid" ]
}
```

And rendering it via NEATO (which is installed with Graphviz) from the command line...

...is rendered as this...

[image: NEATO rendered sequence diagram example]

To use NEATO to render the above image, do you the following:

1. Install NEATO, which comes with Graphviz (at least it does on a Mac when using `$ brew install graphviz # requires Homebrew`)
2. Place the `digraph sequenceDiagramExample {...}` code from above in a text file called `sequenceDiagramExample.dot`
3. From the command line, run `$ neato -Tpng sequenceDiagramExample.dot -o sequenceDiagramExample.png`, which will generate a PNG file called `sequenceDiagramExample.png`
4. View the PNG :)

## Pro-tip - Don't confuse the `neato` with `dot` executables

- `neato` is probably what you want to use when you want granular control over how elements are positioned (alternate viewpoints in comments welcome!)
- Don't confuse rendering with `neato` vs. rendering with `dot` (which is also included with Graphviz)
- For example, rendering the directed graph from Suggestion #2 using `dot` (e.g. `$ dot -Tpng sequenceDiagramExample.dot -o sequenceDiagramExample.png`) will produce this...

[image]