# using graphviz to create tcp flow diagrams?

Tags: graph, graphviz, graph-drawing, network-flow

Does graphviz or it's sub-projects support tcp flow type diagrams, e.g:

[image]

I've looked through the graphviz documentation and gallery, but nothing jumps out at me.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/. Its syntax is like graphviz.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this type of graph is called a [Sequence Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram).

In Graphviz there is no way to draw a line (in Graphviz, this is called an edge) from the middle of another line. To simulate this behavior in Graphviz, a node is created in the middle of the first edge, and from this node begins a second edge (perpendicularly or slanted to the first edge):

```
digraph {
    splines=false
    node [shape=box
          fontname="Arial"
          style="filled, rounded"
          fillcolor="#e2e2f0"]
    
    b_start [label="Bob"]
    b_0 [label="" shape=point height=0] // it is helper invisible node
    b_1 [label="" shape=point height=0] // it is helper invisible node
    b_end [label="Bob"]
    b_start -> b_0 -> b_1 -> b_end [style="dashed" arrowhead="none"]
    
    a_start [label="Alice"]
    a_0 [label="" shape=point height=0] // it is helper invisible node
    a_1 [label="" shape=point height=0] // it is helper invisible node
    a_end [label="Alice"]
    a_start -> a_0 -> a_1 -> a_end [style="dashed" arrowhead="none"]
    
    {rank=same;
     b_0 -> a_0 [weight=0
                 arrowhead=vee fontname="Arial"
                 label=<<B>1 </B>Authentication Request>]}
    {rank=same;
     a_1 -> b_1 [weight=0
                 arrowhead=vee fontname="Arial"
                 label=<<B>2 </B>Authentication Response>]}
}
```

[image: sequence diagram example made with graphviz dot]

So **you can draw it in Graphviz, but the script will be larger and less semantic than using a specific language for sequence diagrams like [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram) or [Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/sequenceDiagram), etc**. Example using PlantUML:

```
@startuml
autonumber
Bob -> Alice : Authentication Request
Bob <- Alice : Authentication Response
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML example]

However, I have **not found how to make slanted lines with PlantUML** ([1](https://forum.plantuml.net/6435/slanted-lines-in-sequence-diagram), [2](https://forum.plantuml.net/9228/slanted-crossing-arrows-in-sequence-diagrams)), so maybe Graphviz will suit you for your drawing, proof of concept with Graphviz:

```
digraph "TCP sequence diagram" {
    splines=false
    nodesep=1
    node [shape=plain fontname="Arial"]
    
    inv_col [style=invis] // left invisible column
    inv_0 [shape=point style=invis]
    inv_1 [shape=point style=invis]
    inv_2 [style=invis]
    inv_col -> inv_0 -> inv_1 -> inv_2 [style=invis]
    
    cl_start [label="CLIENT"]
    cl_end [style=invis]
    cl_0 [label="" shape=point height=.005 group=g1]
    cl_1 [label="" shape=point height=.005]
    cl_2 [label="" shape=point height=.005]
    cl_start -> cl_0 -> cl_1 -> cl_2 -> cl_end [arrowhead="none"]
    
    {rank=same;inv_col;cl_start;hp_start}
    {rank=same;inv_0;cl_0}
    {rank=same;inv_1;cl_2}
    inv_0 -> cl_0 [weight=0 arrowhead=vee fontname="Arial" label="connect"]
    inv_1 -> cl_2 [weight=0 arrowhead=vee fontname="Arial" label="http request"]
    inv_2 -> cl_end [weight=0 style=invis]
    
    hp_start [label="HAPROXY"]
    hp_end [style=invis]
    hp_0 [label="" shape=point height=.005]
    hp_1 [label="" shape=point height=.005]
    hp_2 [label="" shape=point height=.005]
    hp_3 [label="" shape=point height=.005]
    hp_start -> hp_0 -> hp_1 -> hp_2 -> hp_3 -> hp_end [arrowhead="none"]
    
    cl_0 -> hp_1 [weight=0 arrowhead=vee fontname="Arial" xlabel="SYN"]
    hp_1 -> cl_1 [weight=0 arrowhead=vee fontname="Arial" xlabel="SYN, ACK of SYN"]
    cl_1 -> hp_2 [weight=0 arrowhead=vee fontname="Arial" label="ACK"]
    cl_2 -> hp_3 [weight=0 arrowhead=vee fontname="Arial" label="http request"]
    
    r_col [style=invis] // right invisible column
    r_0 [shape=point style=invis]
    r_1 [shape=point style=invis]
    {rank=same;cl_0;r_0}
    {rank=same;hp_3;r_1}
    r_col -> r_0 [style=invis]
    r_0 -> r_1 [dir=both label="Tq" arrowhead=vee arrowtail=vee fontname="Arial"]
}
```

[image: TCP flow sequence diagram with slanted lines made with graphviz dot]

Related answer: [Graphviz top to bottom AND left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491322/graphviz-top-to-bottom-and-left-to-right#answer-53470455)

Comment: Regarding the plantuml part see also: https://forum.plantuml.net/9228/slanted-crossing-arrows-in-sequence-diagrams

Comment: @albert thank you for the clarification, but that link was already in my answer.

Comment: You are right, though due to the fact that it was just with 1,2 I completely missed it a bit more descriptive text might have helped.